# Ubuntu 13.04 custom keyboard layout

Tags: 13.04, lenovo, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, print-screen

Using Ubuntu 13.04, I want the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key to work as <kbd>Menu</kbd> on Lenovo S430 keyboard.

```
/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/user/.Xmodmap
```

with modified line

```
keycode 107 = Menu NoSymbol Menu NoSymbol Menu
```

Does not work.
Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried using the keyboard shortcut settings? In the dash type "keyboard" to open the keyboard settings dialog. Select tab *Shortcuts*, then click *Windows* and select *Activate the Windows Menu*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add the following line at the end of `~/.Xmodmap` file:

```
keycode 107 = Menu
```

Second, run this command in terminal:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Third, go to **System settings** → **Keyboard**, select **Shortcuts** tab, go to **Screenshots** and disable or change the value for **Take a screenshoot** (this doesn't have to be anymore <kbd>Print</kbd> key)

Comment: Worked, thanks.
Not sure why disabling the shortcut was necessary, but this was what I was missing..